# Oracle. Мутирование таблицы

Tags: oracle

У меня есть таблица:

```
create table NX_NUMBER_POOLS
(
  nbpl_id    NUMBER(10) not null,
  pool_start NUMBER(12) not null,
  pool_end   NUMBER(12) not null,
  region     VARCHAR2(100) not null,
  branch     VARCHAR2(100) not null
)
```

И 2 триггера

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NX_CHECK_NUMBER_POOL_TRG
   after insert or update on NX_NUMBER_POOLS
   for each row
begin
   if (not nx_warehouse_pg.latch) then
      nx_warehouse_pg.update_pool;
   end if;
end;
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER save_values
   before insert or update on NX_NUMBER_POOLS
   for each row
begin
  if (not nx_warehouse_pg.latch) then
    nx_warehouse_pg.pool_start := :new.pool_start;
    nx_warehouse_pg.pool_end := :new.pool_end;
  end if;
end;
```

И пакет nx_warehouse_pg

```
create or replace package body NX_WAREHOUSE_PG is
   procedure update_pool is
   begin
      latch := true;
      for rec in (select pool_start, pool_end, nbpl_id from NX_NUMBER_POOLS) loop
         if (nx_warehouse_pg.pool_start between rec.pool_start and
            rec.pool_end) then
            raise_application_error(-20000,
                                    ' Начало пула не должно пересекаться с диапозоном значений другого. ' || rec.nbpl_id);
         end if;

         if (nx_warehouse_pg.pool_end between rec.pool_start and
            rec.pool_end) then
            raise_application_error(-20000,
                                    ' Конец пула не должен пересекаться с диапозоном значений другого. ' || rec.nbpl_id);
         end if;
      end loop;
      latch := false;
   exception
      when others then
         latch := false;
         raise;
   end;
end NX_WAREHOUSE_PG;
/
```

```
create or replace package NX_WAREHOUSE_PG is
   ----------
   --Переменные для хранения изменившихся или новых значений полей pool_start и pool_end таблицы nx_number_pools
   pool_start number;
   pool_end   number;
   --Защелка для предупреждения повторного вызова триггеров.
   latch boolean := false;
   --Проверка начала и конца нового пула.
   procedure update_pool;
end NX_WAREHOUSE_PG;
```

При инсерте в таблицу все ок, при апдейте ногово значения появляется ошибка мутации таблицы.
В чем проблема? Насколько я понял нельзя чтобы в триггере происходила выборка из изменяемой таблицы и для этого как раз делают отдельные процедуры, которые будут этим заниматься, так я и сделал.
Можете подсказать что не так и что нужно сделать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Почему вы решили эту логику реализовать в триггере, а не там, где вы делаете insert, update? Обычно, ошибка мутации указывает на ошибку в дизайне приложения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбирать из таблицы при ее `UPDATE`, `DELETE` нельзя ни в самом триггере, ни в процедурах, которые вызываются из триггера. При `DELETE` ситуация еще усложняется, т.к. это правило распространяется на зависимые таблицы по ключам (*foreign keys*).

Для обработки такой ситуации обычно используется следующий алгоритм: сначала запоминаются в массив все идентификаторы изменяемых записей, затем в триггере на действие (без `FOR EACH ROW`) выполняется обработка.

В ORACLE есть специальный тип триггеров для обработки данной ситуации `COMPOUND TRIGGER`. Они имеют секцию для хранения переменных на всем протяжении выполнения `UPDATE` или `DELETE`.

Вот ссылка на [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/256655/) и [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020).