# Ошибки компиляции при создании COMPOUND TRIGGER

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть триггер:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER nx_check_number_pool_trg_test
   for insert or update ON nx_number_pools
   COMPOUND TRIGGER

   t_pool_start number(12);
   t_pool_end   number(12);

   BEFORE STATEMENT IS
   begin
      t_pool_start := :new.pool_start;
      t_pool_end   := :new.pool_end;
      end;
   END BEFORE STATEMENT;

   before EACH ROW IS
   begin
      for rec in (select pool_start, pool_end, nbpl_id from NX_NUMBER_POOLS) loop
         if (t_pool_start between rec.pool_start and rec.pool_end) then

            raise_application_error(-20000,
                                    ' Начало пула не должно пересекаться с диапозоном значений другого. ' ||
                                    rec.nbpl_id);
         end if;

         if (t_pool_end between rec.pool_start and rec.pool_end) then
            raise_application_error(-20000,
                                    ' Конец пула не должен пересекаться с диапозоном значений другого. ' ||
                                    rec.nbpl_id);
         end if;
      end loop;
      end;
   END before EACH ROW;
END nx_check_number_pool_trg_test;
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Compilation errors for TRIGGER BIS.NX_CHECK_NUMBER_POOL_TRG_TEST

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

          before after
Line: 18
Text: if (t_pool_start between rec.pool_start and rec.pool_end) then
```

Можете сказать что я не так делаю?

Comment: У вас синтаксическая ошибка? Какие сложности у вас возникли при поиске и устранении этой ошибки? Номер строки неверный?

Comment: Не понимаю где нашелся сивол ; на указанной строке.

Comment: Зависит от версии БД и инструмента, которым вы вызываете SQL предложение. Были баги с номерами строк. Первая ошибка у вас в 12 строке.

Comment: то исправил, спасибо, теперь получаю новую:
Compilation errors for TRIGGER BIS.NX_CHECK_NUMBER_POOL_TRG_TEST

Error: PLS-00679: trigger binds not allowed in before/after statement section
Line: 16
Text: nx_warehouse_pg.update_pool(t_pool_start, t_pool_end);

Error: PLS-00679: trigger binds not allowed in before/after statement section
Line: 17
Text: END After each row;

Comment: Ну устраните её тоже. Почему это вызывает у вас затруднение?

Comment: Да, как понял [это связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1116376/217579). Там вы не ответили на мой комментарий. Подозреваю, то что вы сейчас делаете вообще не нужно. Или вы просто тренируетесь?

Comment: Таблица будет модифицироваться вручную в БД, поэтому нужен триггер. Не могу исправить потому что видимо не понимаю концепции. У таких триггеров 4 секции:
Before statement,
After statement,
Before each row,
After each row.
И ни в одну не могу затолкать все что начинается с for rec in

Comment: _Таблица будет модифицироваться вручную в БД, поэтому нужен триггер_, неверное утверждение. Сделайте процедуру для модификации таблицы и дайте на неё права, тому кто будет ею пользоваться, а права на прямое изменение таблицы  наоборот отзовите, чтобы что-то не испортил. Так будет правильно.

Comment: _Не могу исправить потому что видимо не понимаю концепции_, а какую концепцию тут нужно понимать? Надо только устранить ошибки синтаксиса. Какой подход нужен по устранения ошибок синтаксиса вы знаете?

Answer (score 3):

Вот рабочее решение, как было задумано в вопросе:

```
create table nx_number_pools (nbpl_id number, pool_start number, pool_end number);
create or replace type poolRow force is object (nbpl_id number, pool_start number, pool_end number)
/
create or replace type poolRows is table of poolRow
/
create or replace trigger nx_check_number_pool_trg_test for insert or update on nx_number_pools compound trigger
    pools poolRows := poolRows (); 
    before each row is begin  
        pools.extend;
        pools(pools.last) := poolRow (:new.nbpl_id, :new.pool_start, :new.pool_end);
    end before each row; 
    after statement is 
    begin  
        for r in (
            select /*+ first_rows(1) */ 
                n.nbpl_id nid, n.pool_start ns, n.pool_end ne, o.nbpl_id oid, o.pool_start os, o.pool_end oe   
            from table (pools) n
            join nx_number_pools o on ((
                n.pool_start between o.pool_start and o.pool_end or 
                n.pool_end between o.pool_start and o.pool_end) and o.nbpl_id != n.nbpl_id)) loop 
            raise_application_error (-20000,
                'Начало/Конец пула не должен пересекаться с другим диапозоном (new=>old='||
                r.nid||'/'||r.ns||'/'||r.ne||'=>'||r.oid||'/'||r.os||'/'||r.oe||')');
        end loop; 
    end after statement;  
end;
/
```

Проверить как работает так:

```
insert into nx_number_pools values (1, 10, 20);
1 row inserted.

insert into nx_number_pools values (2, 21, 30);
1 row inserted.

insert into nx_number_pools values (3, 15, 25);
ORA-20000: Начало/Конец пула не должен пересекаться с другим диапозоном (new=>old=3/15/25=>1/10/20)
```

---

PS Пример служит только для изучения концепции триггеров. Применение в продуктивной среде не рекомендуется, так как триггер для решения данной задачи не нужен.